# can bash be configured such that ctrl-W deletes words correctly?

Tags: bash, readline

Readline offers us two different functions to delete a word, neither appears to be configurable, and neither does the right thing. Is there some voodoo I can perform which will combine the behaviors and give me what I expect?

```
**** Bind ctrl-W to backward-kill-word ****

% the "quick brown" fox
                        ^
% the "quick brown"        # 1x
                    ^
% the "quick               # 2x
             ^
% the "                    # 3x
       ^
%                          # 4x
  ^
```

Nope: doesn't understand a quoted string is a single word.

```
**** Bind ctrl-W to shell-backward-kill-word ****

% the "quick brown" fox
                        ^
% the "quick brown" fox    # 1x
                       ^
% the "quick brown"        # 2x
                   ^
% the                      # 3x
     ^
%                          # 4x
  ^
```

Nope: closer, but the insistence on positioning the cursor right on top of the previous word, and of deleting a single space in the same situation where backward-kill-word correctly kills the entire word, makes this intolerable to use.

Here's what I might have thought would be the default behavior, yet I can't elicit it.

```
% the "quick brown" fox
                        ^
% the "quick brown"        # 1x ctrl-W
                    ^
% the                      # 2x ctrl-W
      ^
%                          # 3x ctrl-W
  ^
```

Edit: I'm happy to say that I've found my way to a macro which accomplishes this, at least in this simple case. Time will tell if it holds up.

```
Meta-w: shell-backward-kill-word
Meta-s: delete-horizontal-space
Control-w: "\M-s\M-w "
```

Comment: I think "correct" might be in the eye of the beholder. The macro you figured out looks interesting, I think you should make it an answer.